# Bot like random phrase comments

Tags: discussion, moderation, bot

I have been seeing comments to questions from user @AgentSmith in this forum that seem unrelated to the question or other comments, and too nonsensical to me to appear like jokes.

E.g. today in
[Why do people hide the assumption contained in the philosophical zombies question/idea?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98675): "This coffin, if it's to fit the body, has to be 200 cm long and 50 cm wide."

[Can radical skepticism be refuted?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39826) "Twins trouble twice"

[About an argument in Famine, Affluence and Morality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97526) "It's hard to be confused in the presence of such clarity, no?"

[What does "A violent man does not die a natural death" mean?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/53538) "This is not even one-third of the story."

A bit difficult to find for me since I cannot get a list of all that users comments in SE, but I used "site:philosophy.stackexchange.com comment Agent Smith" search in Google.

It seems to me in general questions and answers written by this user seem legitimate, but some comments left on questions look like written by a bot (and not a gpt based one mimicking humans, more like a random sentence generator), possibly without the knowledge of the actual user (if credentials got leaked). Since they look spammy but not abusive, i am not sure how else to raise attention to this.

Or am I just not getting the jokes?

I would be curious if there are more such comments by other users.

Is there a way to get a list of all comments by an SE user?

Comment: "A bit difficult to find for me since I cannot get a list of all that users comments in SE" If you go to the user;s profile, then click on "Activity" and "All Actions" all the comments will be listed (for this particular SE at least).

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks. Yes, there are many more such comments.

Comment: I tender my humblest apology if my posts have served to do anything other than clarify/seek clarification in re a question/answer.

Comment: The question was whether those comments (those who are off-topic) were written by you, or by some AI. This apology does not confirm or deny. @AgentSmith

Answer (score 3):

I did register this happening myself, primarily through flags.

Even if they are meant as jokes, this is not what comments are meant for. Thus, I would say this has to stop. Makes nothing but noise and workload (flags).

...as it's not even funny

Comment: It now started generating answers, too: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/102699/30526

"Ask that question to a pan (chimp). Warning. You might have to use sign language + no guarantees whether a pan can comprehend the question."